# Flexbox: 2 column grid with empty first column

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to align a 2 column grid, where the items on the 2nd row align with the 2nd column? This is difficult to explain textually, so I drew up what I'm aiming for.

[image]

Ideally, I would prefer

- no swapping CSS classes via JS.
- the label to have a `max-width`, but grow up until that point.

Comment: curious why the two label tags are aligned differently in the first example.

Comment: please post enough code in the question to reproduce the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @chovy: That's the design spec.

Comment: @Michael_B I did below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37354795/398574

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there are two possible answers to this that don't invlolve `flexbox`.

1. `display: table-row`
2. CSS Grids

```css
.tableContainer {
  display: table-row;
  background: red;
}
input {
  background: yellow;
}
label {
  background: aquamarine;
}
.inputLabel {
  display: table-cell;
}
.error {
  font-size: smaller;
  font-style: italic;
  display: table-row;
}

/* */ 

inputLabel_GridItem,
.error_GridItem {
  display: initial;
}

.inputLabel_GridItem {
  grid-area: label;
  padding: 20px;
}

.error_GridItem {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  grid-area: error;
  padding: 20px;
}

.gridContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 300px;
  grid-template-areas: "label input""....... error";
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2> display: table </h2>

<form novalidate class="tableContainer">
  <label for="textField" class="inputLabel">Name</label>
  <input type=text id="textField" placeholder="full name" />
  <label for="textField" class="error">error</label>
</form>

<h2> CSS Grids </h2>
<form novalidate class="gridContainer">
  <label for="textField" class="inputLabel_GridItem">Name</label>
  <input type=text id="textField" placeholder="full name" />
  <label for="textField" class="error_GridItem">error</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

put element 2 and element 3 in a another container div element so every child of it will use the same widths (of the container). give the container a max-width so that it won't get bigger that that size.

make element 1 `float: left` so it floats to the left only if there is enough space.

that is the basics. maybe you'll need media queries or further styling for the exact behaviour you want.

but the idea is:
1 floats beside the container containing 2 and 3 when there is enough width to the screen.